# Is it ok for me (Not Hindu) to wear a turban/head wrap to represent the Hindu character I am playing in a play?

Tags: practice, culture, non-hindu

I have done a bit on research into this, and I plan to do more, but I am looking for a more personal answer from people who are Hindu. If you can help, please do, as I need it. I am attempting to educate myself on this religion, and any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: According to scriptures, even during Natak (sanskrit word for play), which is not real-life, there are certain regulations, like not displaying Yagnopaveet (sacred thread) on bare-body if not initiated, chanting mantras loudly especially if not initiated, only husband-wife are allowed to play romantic roles (otherwise it falls under partial adultery) etc. Most importantly, you should not misrepresent the person/religion you're portraying e.g. wearing Hindu symbols and doing villain stuff with agenda of portraying all Hindus as such, to mislead audiences, is the biggest no-no.

Comment: Assuming no malice agenda, it is also important to portray the head-wrap correctly. There are hundreds of religious sects in India, each with their own style of turban. Usually Sikhs are associated with turbans to western world. And then ignorant people confuse even turbans with Muslims. So in a nutshell 1. research costume 2. avoid malice 3. avoid deep religious/spiritual portrayals (imagine playing a bloodied barebody Jesus christ with no faith in Jesus/Christianity or worse, an atheistic mindset)

Comment: Regarding whether it is at all needed for Hindus to cover their heads you can read this answer: https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/a/44626/4732