# Wearing Turbun/cloth on head

Tags: worship

In [this answer](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/44625/custom-of-covering-head-with-handkerchief-in-temple/44626?r=SearchResults&s=4%7C14.7792#44626) it is mentioned that head covering allowed only certain instances but not during worship.

But we do see priests wearing turban when carrying utsava murthy for proceedings, like in the attached image from Sringeri mutt.

In what situations one must wear head scarf or turban?

[image]