# Trimming of Shikha/tuft

Tags: rituals, customs

It has already been discussed [here](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/32169/are-grooming-dress-rules-prescribed-for-brahmins/32173?r=SearchResults&s=3%7C15.8063#32173) that without Shikha, one is considered naked and hence shaving is not allowed.

My question is, can it be trimmed to certain length?

If not trimmed, it would grow quite long but we normally see a short tuft in many. So, length reduction acceptable?